# Ubuntu 17.10, dock icons disappear after a while

Tags: 17.04, dock

I've installed Ubuntu 17.04 on my Asus UX301L.

I notice that the dock icons disappear without any reason after a while.

They will appear again only if I move the dock from bottom to left or right.

Comment: just an update, i Notice that this issue is present only when I connect the apple magic mouse, while using other mouses the issue desappear

Comment: I've just started using my magic mouse and the same thing happened, so I think you're onto something. Using 17.10. Thanks for the tip on moving the dock around to make them reappear.

Comment: I have submitted a bug report for this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock/+bug/1737528

Comment: Having the same issue when accidental pressing the middle button/mouse wheel. you're hack on replacing the dock worked for me for now.